# Ho can I use adMob library for iOS without using -all_load linker flag

Tags: ios, admob

I'm adding adMob provide by google to my iOS app and I'm stuck on this part of the installation:
Add -all_load under Other Linker Flags in the project build info

If I add that flag, then another third party library breaks giving me the error message:

ld: duplicate symbol _vw_chartype_table_p in /Users/josh/ Projects/app/libs/libvt_universal.a(vw_ctype-3279EF26D0C25F3A.o) and / Users/josh/Projects/app/libs/ libvt_universal.a(vw_ctype-34AB9EC0B46D954C.o) for architecture i386

Is there any way to use the adMob library without using -all_load? For example, I've tried -force_load $(SOURCE_ROOT)/adMob/libGoogleAdMobAds.a
but
ld: file not found: /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/latest/bbbb/APPNAME/adMob/libGoogleAdMobAds.a

Comment: Have you tried `-ObjC` instead? (all_load is not needed for recent Xcode [llvm] versions).

Comment: Yes I have used your suggested linker flag -ObjC but its show agin json duplicate error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Google suggests using -all_load is that they are using categories in their code, and Objective-C libraries with categories are not properly loaded by the llvm linker (well that was the case in 4.3 xcode, not sure about 4.4 with the newer clang).

So, I guess if you are brave you can try to just remove the all_load flag. It should build fine. If the bug is NOT fixed, what will happen is when you run your code, it will crash, since none of the categories the library uses will have been loaded. This might be a good thing to do in any case, as your project should build, and if it does not you can fix those problems first.

What I do suggest you do is use -force_load, which has llvm load the categories in the adMob library (among other things). To use it you MUST have a fully qualified path (ie starts at '/') to the library. Obviously if you use Terminal and run:

ls -l /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/latest/bbbb/APPNAME/adMob/libGoogleAdMobAds.a

its going to fail. So enter the proper path - hard coded - for now to just see if you can get the project to first build, then run. If it does you can later figure out what is the appropriate $(VAR) to use to find it inside your project.